# Required parameters but none were supplied error

Tags: selenium, testng

Can someone help me on how to fix the error and run the script?

```
public class ExcelCapture {

public WebDriver driver;

String filePath = "E:\\Study\\workspace\\OCM25_26_OCE_19\\OCM25_26_OCE_19\\BlackDogFrameWork\\TestData\\Test_Data.xlsx";

@BeforeClass
public String excelFunction(String sheetName, int rowNum, int colNum) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException  { 

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
    Row row = sh.getRow(rowNum);
    String data = row.getCell(colNum).getStringCellValue();
    return data;        
}

@Test
public void login() throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException 
{       driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
    String userName1 = excelFunction("datad", 1, 2);
    String passWord1 = excelFunction("datad", 1, 3);

    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(userName1);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(passWord1);     
}
```

**Console is throwing the below error:**

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass excelFunction
>   org.testng.TestNGException:  Method excelFunction requires 3
>   parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Configuration annotation.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because `excelFunction` has 3 parameters and has `@BerforeClass` annotation, when you have parameters for function with annotation then you have to pass the parameters before annotation tags as follow.

```
 @Parameters({ "sheetname", "row-number", "colBNum" })
 @BeforeClass
    public String excelFunction(String sheetName, int rowNum, int colNum) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException  { 

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
```

and pass parameter values from `testng.xml` as shown below

```
<suite name="Test Suite">
    <test name="Testing">
    <parameter name="sheetname" value="Your SheetName"/>
    <parameter name="row-number" value="your row number"/>
    <parameter name="colBNum" value="Your Column number"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.parameterization.TestParameters" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```